# css scroll only horizontal cross browser

Tags: css, horizontal-scrolling

I need to make a `div` only horizontal scrollable, this is what I tried but does not work (actually I'm using chrome)

```
overflow-y: scroll;
overflow-x: hidden;
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/21xdv6mc/)**

Comment: Could you please post your code, or the website if it is online. I can not really diagnose the problem without the code. Thank You! :)

Comment: Neo, if that is the code, then it is displaying perfectly. Is the website online? If so just post the link and I can view the style/source.

Comment: @MichaelJones actually on chrome win7, at least on my computer, this is not horizontal scrollable.. please help http://jsfiddle.net/cgbwvd8g/

Comment: Oh my gosh neoDev, I feel so stupid. I was not thinking clearly, let me take another look at it! :)

Comment: neoDev, the problem is the boxs are using page percentages. That will make it so the divs never have to scroll sideways. To accomplish what you are looking for you would need to use pixels. Also, why use Jquery to do this? Why not just use plain old CSS/HTML?

Comment: @MichaelJones please can you show me how please :) http://jsfiddle.net/21xdv6mc/

Comment: Sure, give me a couple of minutes to make a nice example.

Comment: @MichaelJones ok, just think a slide stuff idea ok?

Comment: Yep of course. I know exactly what you mean, I once made a side scrolling website! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this fiddle

`JS Fiddle`

Comment: omg!!! thank you so much man!! do you think this is cross browser/device? this is what I had in mind http://jsfiddle.net/sLvezrur/1/, thank you for help :)

Comment: Yea, his code will work across all browsers. You can see if certain properties will work by using this website: http://caniuse.com/